# How to get the name of arguments that are given to a function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments

So I have the function:

```
def res_print(table, naam):
    print(f'{naam}', end=' ') 
    print(f'#{len(table)}')
```

When I excute it:

```
>>> res_print(employees, 'employees')
```

I will get for example:

```
>>> employees #250
```

Now is there any way I can just do:

```
>>> res_print(employees)
>>> employees #250
```

Comment: ```print(f'{naam}', end=' ')```
```print(f'#{len(str(naam)}')```? Can you share what is ```employee```

Comment: Coupling presentation data with variable names would be bad practice and certainly lead to all sorts of problems later on...

Comment: @Sujay OP don't want to send the `naam` argument.

Comment: You cannot do this. The variable name ``employees`` is only known to its specific scope. Within ``res_print`` only the variable name ``table`` is know. You cannot get the name of arbitrary variables referencing the same object.

Comment: What result do you expect for a call such as ``res_print(companies["my_company"].employees)`` or ``emps = employees; res_print(emps)``?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
employees=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
print([k for k in list(locals().keys()) if not k.startswith("_")][0],f"#{len(employees)}")
#OR
print([k for k in list(locals().keys()) if not k.startswith("_")][-1],f"#{len(employees)}")
#Which will take last one!
```

OR For doing in function try this:

```
def f(table):
    print([k for k in list(globals().keys()) if not k.startswith("_") and k!="f"],f"#{len(employees)}")
f(employees)
```

This will not work most of the time but .... I just wanna share.